# problem in load dynamic webpage (I want to indicate which part of my page load first in classic asp and also asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, iis

we are creating a custom content management and out portal page is bit bulky it is about 60Kb without images.

and during loading the page in some browser we can see some parts of site load faster than the other parts of the site where as we want to indicate (or instruct the web server) to load some of the areas first then load rest of the page.

is there any particulat setting in IIS for is there any particular method in classic asp for doing that?
also I have the same question in asp.net.

best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built in way to describe which parts of a page load first in either ASP or ASP.Net. It really isn't a server decision - depends on how your browser parses the page and then requests the additional resources (or renders the existing ones).

You could potentially use AJAX and build in the order each section loads either as a state engine or by chaining. Seems to be pretty complicated for the benefit.

If you just don't want the user to see anything until the entire page loads you can control that from code using buffering. In classic ASP you use Response.Buffer and Response.Flush so the server doesn't start returning HTML until the whole page is ready - it will keep parts of the page from loading (the server won't stream results). I assume ASP.Net has a similar/identical method for buffering. Note that you can't pick sections of code with buffering but you can send only portions (top down) at a time.